# ScriptDb Quota in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Regarding the new ScriptDb service; from the [frequently asked questions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#frequently_asked_questions) section:

> What are the quotas on the database? Currently, the are: 50MB for
>   consumer accounts, 100MB for Google Apps accounts, 200MB for Google Apps
>   for Business/Education/Government accounts
>
> This limit is per-user across all their databases.

Taking the consumer account as an example, does this mean there is a 50MB quota for each database owned by a user, or does the quota apply to all of a user's databases combined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the databases combined. At least that's what they've told me right after the session.

Comment: Thanks Henrique.  Did you get to the "HTML service" session? - might need to pick your brain on that as well, haha.

Comment: :D  I sure did. How could I miss it?! But I still have to start working with it. (on vacation now)